# Why dose the NSString become NSZomie in this code?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I just ran into a problem.I use NSMutableArray to keep the Ad ids that need to be loaded. When one id is preloaded,  I remove it from the array. Then I find out that, after remove, the unit id became a zombie.

I tried to reproduce this, and I find out that when the Ads id was pulled from array, it is not a zombie.It just become zombie after removed from array. But, there is still a NSString* refer to it, how can this happen? And If it will become zombie at this point, it should become zombie every time. But it only happens occasionally.

```
 -(void)preloadNextRewardVideo
 {
     if([_allRewardVideoAds count])
     {
         NSString* adsName = [_allRewardVideoAds objectAtIndex:0];  //the element is not a zombie here
         GADRewardBasedVideoAd* ads = [self ensureRewardVideo:adsName];
         if(![ads isReady])
         {
             _currentRewardVideoName = adsName;
             [_allRewardVideoAds removeObjectAtIndex:0];
             GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
             [ads loadRequest:request withAdUnitID:adsName];  //here, adsName is a zombie
             _isRewarLoading = YES;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have ARC on?

Comment: @bbum No, I don't have ARC on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth taking a close look at cocoa's [memory management policies](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). The thing here (it seems to me) is that when your code assigns the string adsName, the object the `preloadNextRewardVideo` method is part of doesn't take ownership of the string-object that `adsName` is pointing at ('ownership' in this context means either allocating and initializing space for it through alloc/init, new, copy, etc, or sending it an explicit retain message). All you have is a local variable that points at a string-object owned by the `_allRewardVideoAds` array. Yes, making the assignment increases the retain count, but that retain is autoreleased, and limited to the scope of this method. As soon as this method ends, nothing is going to own that string-object, and it will deallocate.

This would not be an issue (and would not create the NSZombie flag) except that you just sent `adsName` to a different object (`GADRewardBasedVideoAd* ads`) that I'm guessing does not retain it either. Of course, `ads` is also autoreleased (nothing owns it outside of this method), but what is that, a race-condition over whether `ads` or `adsName` is deallocated first?  I suspect you *do* have a race-condition because NSZombie only shows up sometimes, but I don't know enough about the internal mechanisms of autorelease to know how that might work.

I think NSZombie is just telling you that you have an object that is:

- in use by an external object, and
- due to be destroyed shortly though autorelease.

ARC is anticipating a problem, and using NSZombie to let you know.

You could fix this either by using the property setter (e.g. use `self.currentRewardVideoName = adsName`) which retains the string-object globally for this object, or by locally copying it (`NSString* adsName = [[_allRewardVideoAds objectAtIndex:0] copy]`) which makes sure that your object owns the string to the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean that assign to a local pointer will implicitly do a retain and a autorelease? Even ARC is not on? Because I am not using ARC here.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed you were using ARC. The only real difference is that ARC does a lot of the retain/release bookkeeping behind the scenes. But the main point still holds: no object owns `adsName` after you remove it from the array. If ARC were on you would get an automatic retain/autorelease when you assigned the string to `adsName`, but ARC is off and you don't send the variable a retain/autorelease explicitly, so as soon as the object is removed from the array (objects coming out of collections are released, not autoreleased) its retain count drops to zero.

Comment: That is the confusing part, If retain won't be auto called in non-ARC mode, I should always encounter this problem. Why it happens only occasionally?

Comment: Will turning ARC on solve my problem? If I turn ARC on, since I never thought of ARC when I writing this, will my code have some potential memory problem?

Comment: I think you only encounter the problem sporadically because release and deallocation don't necessarily have a strict order; if two objects are on the deallocation queue you can't be sure which will die first, and if there's a dependency you'll only get a problem if the wrong one dies first. Turning on ARC will mean a bunch of rewriting and refactoring because ARC has a different design pattern. I suggest you read up on it first before you take that step.

Comment: Ok, I will read about ARC carefully. I tend to use ARC since there are a lot of code written in this style, and checking every pointer assignment is a hard thing.

Comment: Almost, @TedWrigley.   `NSZombie` means the object has already been deallocated.   It has already been autoreleased to the point of deallocation.  When zombies are enabled, the runtime drops the ISA for the zombie onto the former object as it is being deallocated.

Comment: Note that `-copy` in manual retain-release would lead to a leak of non-constant strings.

Comment: @bbum: thanks for that bit on NSZombie. I'm pretty sure I get that. I'm not sure I understand the second part, though. Why would copy in a manual retain-release lead to a leak? Are you just thinking about releasing the copy, or is there something I'm missing? Friggin' thank g*d for ARC, though...

Comment: "I think NSZombie is just telling you.... due to be destroyed shortly through autorelease".  That's wrong;  an object is already destroyed if it has been turned into a zombie.

Comment: `-copy` returns an object with a +1 retain count.  That needs to be balanced with `autorelease` or `release` or else the copy will leak.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't enable ARC that means you need to manually manage the memory by yourself. Since you don't enable ARC that means you need to manually manage the memory by yourself. Even though most of APIs will return an auto released object from a method but that's not always be the case.

For this case, NSArray retains the objects contained in itself so it may not need to return an auto released object from objectAtIndex: method since it should be retained by itself as an optimization. In this case I suggest you to call retain the object when you get it from the array and release it before the end of this method. That would help for this case.

Comment: Thanks, I have turned ARC on for the file, now it works fine. it is a pity I can't mark more than 1 answer to be "right" because you are very helpful too.

Comment: It's OK. I'm glad my answer can help you. Please mark the answer that fit your need more :)